# Selenium Python - How to drag the button?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

I test the website `"https://letcode.in/slider"`. It supports **clicking the button (Solution 1)** or **dragging the button (Solution 2)**.
I wrote the simple code to test it, but I do not know how to perform the solution 2 - drag the button.
Do you have any idea?

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains


def SelectableSlider():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://letcode.in/slider")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    slider = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='generate']")
    print("slider size: " + str(slider.size))
    knob = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='generate']")
    # +SOLUTION1 Click the button
    knob.send_keys("23")
    knob.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    # +SOLUTION2 Drag the button ???

    # Find and click the generate button
    getCountryBtn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button is-primary']")
    getCountryBtn.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    verifyCount = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h1[@class='subtitle has-text-info']").text
    print("verifyCount: " + verifyCount + " - Substring: " + verifyCount.replace("Word limit : ", ""))
    resultBoard = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@class='has-text-primary-light']").text
    resultList = resultBoard.split(" - ")
    print("resultList: " + str(resultList) + " - Size: " + str(len(resultList)))
    if str(len(resultList)) == verifyCount.replace("Word limit : ", ""):
        print("Right Result!")
    else:
        print("Wrong Result!")
    
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SelectableSlider()
```

Do you have any idea for solution 2 - drag the button?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the drag and drop using `ActionChains` class. Use the below code:

```
# +SOLUTION2 Drag the button ???
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(knob, 100, 100).perform()
```

Import required:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

**Code explanation:** Above code will drag and drop the cursor by offset of `x=100` and `y=100` co-ordinates. You can increase/decrease the length you want to drag by changing the co-ordinates.